# How to reset and set new value to reverse countdownTimer in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, countdowntimer

**Html**

```
<span id="hms_timer"></span>
<button onclick="resetime()">Reset time for 3hr</button>
```

**Javasript**

```
//Default countdown will start from 2 hour 
$('#hms_timer').countdowntimer({
            hours: 2,
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 0,
            size: "lg"
        });

//Onclick button reset previous countdown
function resetime(){
$('#hms_timer').countdowntimer({
                hours: 3,
                minutes: 0,
                seconds: 0,
                size: "lg" 
            });
}
```

I have used ref link [http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer](http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/)

Here 2 hour has set default for coutdown timer.But when i click on button(timer set successfully to 3 hr) then counter going fast because of old timeout.can you help me?
thanks in advance.